# How to install dwm in void linux

Tags: linux, make, dwm, void-linux

What is it, the dependencies for comiple dwm from scratch
for install dwm (suckless windows manager) in arch linux , i need to install xorg and make and other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Dependencies needed for compile dwm in `void linux` from scratch is:

```
sudo xbps-install base-devel libX11-devel libXft-devel libXinerama-devel freetype-devel fontconfig-devel
```

#### Dependencies needed for compile dwm in `arch linux` from scratch is:

```
sudo pacman -S base-devel libx11 libxft libxinerama freetype2 fontconfig
```